# Produce a filtered version of a GRIB file

Tags: gdal-translate, grib

How can you produce a filtered GRIB file containing a subset of information from an original "bigger" GRIB file?

Let's say I have a GRIB file covering pressure, temperature and wind direction for a large area and for 5 days. I'd like to be able to produce a file with only the data matching: {pressure, days 1 and 2, a geo-rectangle}. How could I approach this?

I found some information about GDAL and specifically gdal_translate. Looks like I could use commands to achieve this but I'm struggling to digest gdal's documentation.

One more option I'm considering is to build my own library (it would be in C#) to parse and write GRIB files, but it seems like a lot of work.

How can this problem be tackled?